# Batch embed video files to html files (with Automator?)

Tags: applescript, automator, script

Can the following be done with Automator, or any other tool/script on macOS?

- I have multiple video files with various file names (always `.mp4`).
- All video files must be embeded in to separate HTML documents.
- The HTML-documents should have the same file name as the video file.
- Both files should be placed together in a zip file.
- The zip file should have the same name as both the video and the HTML file.

So, if I have the file `video-to-html.mp4`, I would like to end up with a zip file containing two files:

```
video-to-html/video-to-html.html
video-to-html/video-to-html.mp4
```

The contents of the HTML file would look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay controls>
<source src="video-to-html.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not a developer, so I do not understand a lot of coding.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you'd want/need to do that?

Comment: Every day I need to upload an amount of video files to a review and approval system.

The system does not allow video files to be uploaded, unless they are embeded in to an HTML-document.

Comment: :/ weird that it doesn't just take the video file. — It is definitely possible to automate, but I'll let smarter people answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this easily with a short shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for v do
    base=${v%%.mp4}
    cat >>"${base}.html" <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay controls>
<source src="$v" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
EOF

    rm -f "${base}.zip"
    zip "${base}.zip" "${base}.html" "$v"
done
```

Save it as a shell script in a convenient place, open Terminal, run `chmod +x name-of-script` and execute as `./name-of-script *.mp4`

Comment: @GeneratorSchj My bad, please remove all the leading space characters in the HTML part (up to and including in front of EOF)

Comment: Got it working! Thanks :)

Would it be possible to have the script doing the whole process automatically just by double clicking the executable file?

Then I would not have to enter Terminal at all :)

Comment: @GeneratorSchj You could define a Folder Action, or use Hazel (preferred). Question probably has come up before on AD though, so before asking a new question use the search function :-)

Comment: patrix, I'm curious... Why do you prefer Hazel? I do because Folder Actions never worked reliably for me. Also a bit easier to manage. Every now and then I see people recommending Folder Actions and I just think of how it barely ever worked. —— @GeneratorSchj, there is an action for triggering a shell script in Automator, so that would be one way to trigger it via a shortcut or application...

Comment: @joonas Hazel is much more reliable and versatile for such things

Comment: Awesome! I got this working with Automator as a program using the code below. I can now simply drag and drop `.mp4` files on to the program icon. Thank you!

`for filename do
    base=${filename%%.mp4}
    cat >>"${base}-HTML-Wrap.html" <<EOF
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lorem ipsum</title>
</head>
<body>
<video autoplay controls loop>
<source src= "${base##*/}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
</body>
</html>
EOF

   zip -j "${base}-HTML-Wrap.zip" "${base}-HTML-Wrap.html" "$filename"

rm -f "${base}-HTML-Wrap.html"

  done`